# CodeMirror only being submitted after second click

Tags: jquery, codemirror

When I click send on my ajax form, all fields are submitted via POST except for CodeMirror.
Only after a second click, all future forms are being submitted correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var options = { 
        target:     '#code',
        beforeSubmit:  function() {
            $('input#submit').attr('value','loading...');
        },
        success:    function() { 
            $('input#submit').attr('value','Submit');
        } 
    };  
    $('#form').submit(function() { 
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
        return false; 
    });


    var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('codeenter'), {
        height: "150px",
        parserfile: "parsecss.js",
        stylesheet: "csscolors.css",
        path: "js/"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('codeenter'), {
    height: "150px",
    parserfile: "parsecss.js",
    stylesheet: "csscolors.css",
    path: "js/"
});
```

Try to add an **onBlur Event**:

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('codeenter'), {
    height: "150px",
    parserfile: "parsecss.js",
    stylesheet: "csscolors.css",
    path: "js/"
    onBlur: function () { 
         editor.save();             
    }
});
```

It will save the content of the editor back to the textarea if the editor loses focus.
Solved the problem in my case.